# Covert Bootstrap columns into rows for small devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a container with 4 rows each row has two columns in 4:8 ratio.
For each column it works perfectly for screens with width more than 1080px, for less than this the content overlaps.

What i want to do, is make all the columns turn into rows with a full width of the screen.

If anyone have any recommendation to get better results please help me.
I have found many questions for people having the same issue and tried their solution but nothing worked for me.

```css
.proctitleleft {
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 90px;
  top: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
}

.procimageleft {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin-right: 90px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.procimageright {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin-left: 90px;
}

.procparagleft1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 138px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.procparagleft2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 138px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.procparagleft3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 138px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="processcontainer">
  <div class="arw_tab_title">
    <div class="tab_title">
      <h2 class="title">The Process</h2>
      <p class=""></p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab_sub_title">
      <h2 class="title">our perfect process</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <div class="proctitleleft">
        <h3>1-Far far away</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="procparagleft1">
        <p>It all started with a farmer and his extraordinary efforts to grow what people later called the best cotton in town
          <br>To Bangladesh we went to see if that was true.And it was!<br>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="procimageleft">
        <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1965/8259/t/4/assets/process1.png">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="procimageright">
          <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1965/8259/t/4/assets/process2.png">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <div class="proctitleleft">
          <h3>2-Lavish Studio left their mark </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="procparagleft2">
          <p>Oh buddy! What can I say?
            <br>Working around the clock to deliver powerful yet very elegant designs that was approved by an internal community before seeing the light of day<br>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <div class="proctitleleft">
          <h3>3-Complete the artwork</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="procparagleft3">
          <p>Partnering up with the same factory that deal with Adidas, Reebok and Name, we were able to transform an idea into a very big powerful reality
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="procimageleft">
          <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1965/8259/t/4/assets/process3.png">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="procimageright">
          <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1965/8259/t/4/assets/process4.png">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <div class="proctitleleft">
          <h3>4- Quality meets perfection
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="procparagleft2">
          <p>We stand by our products because we’re confident in what we deliver.
            <br> That’s why we designed an unsurpassed shopping and unboxing experience to befit such creations
            <br>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `col-md-4` and `col-md-8` instead of `col-xs-*` so you have 4:8 ratio above 992px width and full col-width under 992px. You don't have to do it by your own. It's the standard behavior of bootstrap.

see https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries for further details

Comment: i tried it and it worked but the thecol-md-8 is hidden behind the col-md-4 so the image is the only visible thing, i took this screenshot from the website 
https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1965/8259/t/4/assets/Screen_Shot_2017-05-03_at_12.29.04_AM.png?8028167174678423193

Comment: looks like that other styles like position and float undermine the default behavior.

Comment: i removed the css code and id works perfectly thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

use three classes col-md-4, col-sm-4 and  col-xs-12, last one for smallest devices full width div tag.

Comment: helpful , i have used the last one